# Beacon Chain in Solidity

Tags: eth-2.0

Is it possible to implement Beacon Chain in Solidity within EVM giving the assumption that we may have bigger blocks?

Comment: From what I have read, the Beacon Chain is a proof-of-stake system to generate new blocks. Are you asking about the contracts on which validators (nodes participating in the proof-of-stake validation) deposit their ETH in order to become validators and participate in POS?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge validators management, shards management, reward distribution, randomness, etc 
Looking for ideas for ETHDenver Hackathon

Answer (score 2):

Most of the current Beacon Chain implementations are written in Java, Rust, Nim or Python. However there is recent project which uses Solidity based Deposit Contract for the Beacon Chain. Some of the interesting Beacon Chain implementations are the following >>

- [Python Implementation of Beacon Chain by Ethereum Foundation](https://github.com/ethereum/beacon_chain)
- [Nim Implementaton of Beacon Chain by Status](https://github.com/status-im/nim-beacon-chain)
- [Java Implementation of Beacon Chain by Harmony](https://github.com/harmony-dev/beacon-chain-java)
- [Rust Implementation of Beacon Chain by Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/shasper)